# Best practice to use AFNetworking

Tags: ios, delegates, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I'm not sure if this is a question with a obvious answer but i haven't been able to find any.

I'm using AFNetworking to connect with my REST server. 
I'm doing basic task like uploading and downloading images, posting and getting json etc etc.

What is the best practice to update UI when somethings changes. If for example have successfully downloadet the profile picture and need to change the image inside a tableview.

I only have 1 class that uses AFNetworking my APIConnector

```
APIConnector.h

@interface APIConnector : NSObject

-(void)downloadClientImageToSystem:(NSString *)imageURL;

@end

APIConnector.m
-(void)downloadClientImageToSystem:(NSString *)imageURL{
    //setup
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    //Set url
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",backendURL,imageURL]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    //Create a download task
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[[imageURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"&imgIndex="] lastObject]];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"there was an error downloading profile image");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DLImageFail object:self];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DLImageSucces object:self];
        }
    }];

    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

As you can see this currently is using NSNotificationCenter but is this the best solution? I've been reading about Delegates and blocks and it all just seems about loose. Should i implement AFNetworking inside the classes that needs it, like the class where i try to update my tableview?

Thanks :)

Extra code example

```
-(void)executePostForURL:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict success:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure{
    [httpManager POST:url parameters:dict progress:nil
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
                  //somehow i need to return [responseObject valueForKey:@"updateLabelString"];
              }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

              }];
}
```

I'm trying to call this in viewdidload. This is of course just pseudo code and doesn't work, how do i parse the [responseObject valueForKey@"updateLabelString"] value into my labelToUpdate.text?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSDictionary *dicToSendToServer;
    UILabel *labelToUpdate = @"temp text";

    [apicon executePostForURL:@"serverurl" dictionary:dicToSendToServer success:^(NSString *test){
        labelToUpdate.text = test;
    }failure:nil];
}
```

Comment: Personally, I add success & failure block parameters to my methods that make network requests. The success block will typically take in 1 param (whatever object it is that you're requesting) and the failure block will take in an NSError object.

Comment: I've updated with a section that takes success and failure block parameters. 
How would the solution look like with what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would declare it like this:

```
- (void)executePostForURL:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict success:(void (^)(id objectYouRequested))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

I also like to use `typedef` to avoid some of the block syntax. I typically define the following:

```
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)(id result);
typedef void (^MySubclassedObjectSuccessBlock)(SubclassedObject *object);
typedef void (^FailureBlock)(NSError *error);
```

This then simplifies the method declaration above to:

```
- (void)executePostForURL:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict success:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure;
```

Comment: So to understand i would use this from my TableView like:

[api executePostForUrl:@"url" dictionary:dic succes:^({
     image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"image.png"];
}) failure:^({
    [db savetolog:@"couldn't executepost"];
})];? :)

Comment: When i have done a succesfull executePostForUrl i would like to return a user instance, how do i do this with this method? Using __block User *user; and then dispatch_async(get_main_queue when i've gotten a success?

Comment: Yeah, you can do something like that. Just get a reference to your user object (I'm not sure how exactly your store that in your app) and then pass that object into the success block.

Comment: I've updated the example. In this i'm just trying to update a label with some text i've gotten from the server. I'm still unsure how to do this?

Comment: `- (YourRequestManager *)executePostForURL:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict success:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure;` would be better if you want to cancel this operation some time